# Изменить значение переменной базового класса

Tags: ооп, наследование, php

Поясните что я не так делаю: есть 2 класса, один из них базовый. Пытаюсь изменить значение переменной базового класса, но не получается. Код:

```
class Base_controller {
    public $main_assign = "string base class" ;
    public function set_tpl($page) {
        $this->main_assign = $page ;
    }
}

class Two extends Base_controller {
    public function set_string($page) {
        Base_controller::set_tpl($page) ;
    }
}

$base = new Base_controller() ;
echo $base->main_assign ;
echo "<br />" ;
$two = new Two() ;
echo $two->set_string("string two class") ;
echo $base->main_assign ;
```

Всем спасибо, буду дальше вникать в ООП, переиграл немного, вот таким образом получилось:

```
class Base_controller {
    public function set_tpl($main_assign = "string base class") {
        echo $main_assign ;
    }
}

class Two extends Base_controller {
    public function set_string($page) {
        $this->set_tpl($page) ;
    }
}

$base = new Base_controller() ;
echo $base->set_tpl() ;
echo "<br />" ;
$two = new Two() ;
echo $two->set_string("string two class") ;
echo $base->set_tpl() ;
```

Comment: Вы ожидаете,что после вызова `$two->set_string("string two class")` в `$base->main_assign` будет лежать значение `"string two class"` ?

Comment: Классы и инстансы классов - это разные вещи. Если вы создадите еще один Two, то в нем тоже будет лежать исходный main_assign

Comment: @wstudiokiwi представьте аналогию из реальной жизни. Допустим есть два человека - отец и сын. Сын покупает себе машину. По вашей логике в таком случае у отца тоже должна как по волшебству появиться эта самая машина. Однако же в реальности такого не бывает. Почему? Потому что несмотря на родственные связи, это дав совершенно разных человека

Comment: каким образом можно изменить значение переменной базового класса?

Comment: @wstudiokiwi вы кажется не понимаете разницу между представителем класса и классом. погуглите шаблон "синглтон", кажется вы пытаетесь его изобрести.

Comment: может тогда скажете как правильно выполнить такой алгоритм:
есть базовый класс и потомок. В базовом классе должна быть возможность изменить значение переменной из потомка. 
Это вообще реально?

Comment: @wstudiokiwi вы не понимаете разницу между классом и экземпляром класса. Ваша ошибка именно в этом. Если это по каким-то причинам понять не удается, то постарайтесь спроецировать это на примеры из реальной жизни. ООП придумано не просто так, а именно как возможность отображать объекты реального мира и связи между ними.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Инстансы друг друга не наследуют, вы наследуете описание класса а не его экземпляры. Речь про что - то что вы придумали не бывает в принципе. представьте

```
namespace фабрика;

class Рабочий {
      var инструменты;
      public function __construct() {
           this->инструменты=array();
      }
      public function добавитьИнструмент(инструмент) {
            array_push(this->инструменты,инструмент);
      }
}

class Столяр extends Рабочий {
     public function __construct() {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->добавитьИнструмент('стамеска');
     }
     public function ТоЧтоВыПытаетесьСделать() {
            Рабочий::добавитьИнструмент('фартук');
     }

}

$простоРабочий = new Рабочий();
$простоРабочий2 = new Рабочий(); //чтобы подчеркнуть абсурдность требования

$столяр = new Столяр();
$столяр->ТоЧтоВыПытаетесьСделать();
```

таким образом мы какому-то столяру пытаемся делигировать право вручить каждому рабочему на фабрике фартук, так вот - не получится. надо обойти всех рабочих и каждому вручить фартук. Для этого, можно создать синглтон "Фабрика" в котором хранить списки рабочих, их продукцию, инструменты и прочее (и не надо наследовать рабочих от фабрики).

Comment: >Для этого, можно создать синглтон "Фабрика"

@eicto имхо тут еще оочень рано говорить о синглтонах и фабриках - человек пока еще разницы между классом и экземпляром не понимает

Comment: @DreamChild "фабрика" тут в буквальном смысле - куда рабочие ходят работать. И то ТС нужно называется синглтон.

Comment: @eicto то, что нужно ТС (имхо) - это понять разницу между классом и его экземпляром и научиться работать с классами на самом базовом уровне (то есть его задача, я более чем уверен, не имеет практического назначения, а всего лишь является учебным примером)

Answer (score 0):

Представьте что Класс это - Человек

А Вы, я, [@eicto](/users/11304/eicto), [@DreamChild](/users/10162/dreamchild) и т.д это екземпляры класса Человек.

Comment: но по сути - 1 или несколько человек могут повлиять на Человечество :) а здесь уже не может)). 
Немного разобрался, пошел "учить" дальше

Comment: Человечество это массив экземпляров класса человек,  а не сам класс :)

Comment: @eicto, всё зависит от реалиации :) Человечество можно также классом сделать :)

Comment: @shurik, распишите подробнее, человечество как инстанс общества это легко, а вот какой инстанс человечества вы можете себе представить ?

Comment: Class Humanity implements ArrayAccess, SeekableIterator, Countable, Serializable { ... }  :)